# Which global attributes are useful on each particular HTML tag?

Tags: html, attributes

Many(all?) HTML tags will accept any of the [global attributes](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Attributes/_Global) but typically you will find [wishy-washy words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) like:

> they can be used on all elements, though they may have no effect on
>   some elements

For a given tag, is there a way to know which attributes (are supposed to) have an effect and which are no-ops?

Comment: Experience perhaps? What answer are you looking for? A website listing each attribute and its usage?

Comment: @mplungjan: A reference or matrix detailing which attributes have an effect on a particular element, and which attributes don't.

Comment: This is not good enough? You are only interested in Global Attributes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: @mplungjan That does a good job for the other attributes, but it "punts" on the global attributes.